# How to delete <script>..</script> by regexp in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Now I have this:

```
    String s = "1<script type='text/javascript'>2</script>3<script type='text/javascript'>3</script>5";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<script.*</script>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        s = s.replace(matcher.group(), "");
    }

    System.out.println(s);
```

The result is

> 15

But I need

> 135

In PHP we have /U modificator, but what should I do in Java? I thought about sth like this, but it is incorrect:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<script[^(script)]*</script>");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/982149

Comment: @fildor, this is my test task for the job: to write a web scraper, and can't use 3rd party libraries =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script([^>]*)?>.*?<\/script>
```

Try this.You needed a `?` for lazy match or shorter match.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kO7lO2/3

Comment: This doesn't catch `<script>..</script>`, as the title of the question suggests.

Comment: @stuXnet <script([^>]*)?>.*?<\/script> try now

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` the below regex by empty string:

```
<script [^>]*>[^<]*</script>
```

Comment: Would this replace `<script>alert("Test")</script>`?

Comment: @stuXnet what was your test result? note there is a space after the `<script`